# RemoveCertificate in System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms - is real (NetFramwork 4.7)?

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-framework-version, pkcs#7, pkcs

Net6 has method System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.RemoveCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.removecertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0

Please tell me if it’s realistic, if there is a way (or maybe even an implementation) of a similar method in NetFramwork 4.7 or higher in class System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms ?

By task, it is necessary to remove the certificate data from the signature. Only here’s, how, when there is no method.

Comment: Missing crypto functions in the .NET Framework (compared to .NET Core or later .NET versions) can often be provided with C#/BouncyCastle. Maybe you will find what you need there.